# Who was that DC hero?

Tags: dc, character-identification, young-justice

In the *Young Justice* episode, *Revelation*, a helicopter is knocked out of the sky, and the occupants fall out of the helicopter as it plummets downward.  A hero flies by and saves the occupants.  She was flying in a purple aura, who was this hero?  Shortly after she saved them, we saw the former-Milestone hero, Icon, so maybe the hero in question is another former-Milestone hero.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answer is found in your question. The purple energy field surrounding the heroine makes her identity likely to be Rocket of "[Icon and Rocket](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Icon_%28comics%29)" fame. Her powers were known to project a purple energy field as a manifestation of her manipulating kinetic and potential energies. Her powers were completely artificial in nature and derived from equipment given to her by Icon.

I suspect they took liberties by covering her completely with her purple energy field, but the fact that Icon shows up seconds later cements my belief that it is indeed, Rocket. No other Justice Leaguer has an energy profile similar to that.

Here is an image I believe will support my hypothesis:

[image]